# Mongodb MapReduce for grouping up to n per category using Mongoid

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongoid

I have a weird problem with MongoDB (2.0.2) map reduce.

So, the story goes like this:

I have Ad model (look for model source extract below) and I need to group up to n ads per category in order to have a nice ordered listing I can later use to do more interesting things.

```
# encoding: utf-8
class Ad  
  include Mongoid::Document
  cache
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :title
  field :slug, :unique => true

  def self.aggregate_latest_active_per_category

    map = "function () {
        emit( this.category, { id: this._id });
    }"

    reduce = "function ( key, value ) {
      return { ads:v };
    }"

  self.collection.map_reduce(map, reduce, { :out => "categories"} )

  end
```

All fun and games up until now.

What I expect is to get a result in a form which resembles (mongo shell for `db.categories.findOne()` ):

```
    {
      "_id" : "category_name",
      "value" : {
          "ads" : [
                          {
                            "id" : ObjectId("4f2970e9e815f825a30014ab")
                          },
                          {
                            "id" : ObjectId("4f2970e9e815f825a30014b0")
                          },
                          {
                            "id" : ObjectId("4f2970e9e815f825a30014b6")
                          },
                          {
                            "id" : ObjectId("4f2970e9e815f825a30014b8")
                          },
                          {
                            "id" : ObjectId("4f2970e9e815f825a30014bd")
                          },
                          {
                            "id" : ObjectId("4f2970e9e815f825a30014c1")
                          },
                          {
                            "id" : ObjectId("4f2970e9e815f825a30014ca")
                          },
                          // ... and it goes on and on
          ]
        }
      }
```

*Actually, it would be even better if I could get value to contain only array but MongoDB complains about not supporting that yet, but, with later use of `finalize` function, that is not a big problem I want to ask about.*

Now, back to problem. What actually happens when I do map reduce is that it spits out something like :

```
{
    "_id" : "category_name",
    "value" : {
        "ads" : [
            {
                "ads" : [
                    {
                        "ads" : [
                            {
                                "ads" : [
                                    {
                                        "ads" : [
                                            {
                                                "id" : ObjectId("4f2970d8e815f825a3000011")
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "id" : ObjectId("4f2970d8e815f825a3000017")
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "id" : ObjectId("4f2970d8e815f825a3000019")
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "id" : ObjectId("4f2970d8e815f825a3000022")
                                            },

   // ... on and on and on
```

... and while I could probably work out a way to use this it just doesn't look like something I should get.

So, my questions (finally) are:

1. Am I doing something wrong and what is it?
2. I there something wrong with MongoDB map reduce (I mean besides all the usual things when compared to hadoop)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're doing it wrong. Inputs and outputs of `map` and `reduce` should be uniform. Because they are meant to be executed in parallel, and `reduce` might be run over partially reduced results. Try these functions:

```
var map = function() {
  emit(this.category, {ads: [this._id]});
};

var reduce = function(key, values) {
  var result = {ads: []};

  values.forEach(function(v) {
    v.ads.forEach(function(a) {
      result.ads.push(a)
    });
  });
  return result;
}
```

This should produce documents like:

```
{_id: category, value: {ads: [ObjectId("4f2970d8e815f825a3000011"), 
                              ObjectId("4f2970d8e815f825a3000019"), 
                              ...]}}
```

Comment: You sir are a true hero and a gentleman as far as I am concerned. Just fix the typo in reduce results.ads.push -> result.ads.push :)